# NVDA reads the first letter of the word, then the word from the autocomplete dropdown list

Tags: jaws-screen-reader, nvda

I am working on **.NET** *MVC* project and I have problem with *NVDA* and *JAWS* reader on the dropdown list. It is the dropdown autocomplete list, and when I am navigating with the keyboard, it was reading double values from the dropdown list.

Then I have added `aria-hidden="true"`, and now it is reading the first alphabet of the value, then the value. For example, this dropdown list:

```
car   
apple 
watch
```

It is reading this:

```
c   
car  
a  
apple  
w  
watch
```

What should I do to read only values?

Code from cshtml:

```
 <input id="client" aria-hidden="true" type="text" class="form-control" data-html="true"  placeholder="Enter @Model.ClientTitle">
```

Code from JS:

```
     $('#client').autocomplete({
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        response($.map(clients, function (item, key) {                 
                                return {
                                    label: item.Name + " (" + item.ClientId + ")",
                                    value: item.Name + " (" + item.ClientId + ")",
                                }
                            }
                        }));
                    },
                    select: function (event, ui) {                 
                        event.preventDefault();
                        if (ui.item.value === "") {
                            $('#client').val(null);
                            return false;
                        }
                        $('#client').val(ui.item.label);
                    },
                    response: function (event, ui) {
                        if (!ui.content.length) {
                            var noResult = { value: "", label: "No matches found." };
                            ui.content.push(noResult);
                        }
                    },
                    minLength: 3,
                    delay: 500
                });
```

Comment: Tough to diagnose without seeing how you coded it.

Comment: Can you show more cshtml? An `<input>` with `aria-hidden="true"` is going to cause a lot of problems and breaks the 4th rule of ARIA use - https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#fourth

Comment: But that is the only code in cshtml that is related to the client. I know that, but JAWS and NVDA are reading double values for each element from the dropdown list. What should I do? @slugolicious

                                                        <label for="client">@Model.Client</label>
                                                
                                                    <input id="client" name="client" type="text" class="form-control" data-html="true" placeholder="Enter @Model.ClientTitle">